# class -> array undefined index PHP

Tags: php, class

---

- THIS IS UNSOLVED

---

I have a class that I've put together to do a CRUD for me. Here is the sections that are applicable to my issue.

I am returning the following errors.

```
[07-Apr-2017 15:45:40 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: placeholder in class/LeadStages.php on line 88
[07-Apr-2017 15:45:40 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in class/LeadStages.php on line 90
[07-Apr-2017 15:45:40 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in class/LeadStages.php on line 91
[07-Apr-2017 15:45:40 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: maxchar in class/LeadStages.php on line 93
```

Class

```
class LeadStage {

    /*
    * Create LeadStage. You will need to include the "LeadStage" 
    * in which is being created, the date created, 
    * time created, and the user who created it.
    */

    function __construct() {
        $this->FormFields = new FormFields; 
    }

    // Input Field -> Stage
    function addInputError_New_Element($option) {
        var_dump($option);
        $element = $this->FormFields->InputError_NEW(
            $Error = $option['error'],
            $Value = $option['value'],
            $PlaceHolder = $option['placeholder'],
            $InputName = $option['name'],
            $InputID = $option['id'],
            $InputType = $option['type'],
            $InputLabel = $option['label'],
            $MaxChar = $option['maxchar'],
            $required = $option['required']
        );
        return $element;
    }

    // Select Option -> Status
    function addSelectError_New_Element($option) {

        $element = $this->FormFields->SelectError_NEW(
            $ErrorMSG = $options['error'], 
            $InputLabel = $option['label'], 
            $Class = $option['class'], 
            $DataTargetDIVID = $option['targetid'], 
            $SelectName = $option['name'], 
            $SelectArray = $option['array'], 
            $Value = $option['value'], 
            $required = $option['required'],
            $Value = FALSE
        );

        return $element;

    }

    function addElementToForm($option) {

        if($option['FormField'] = 'stage') {

            // Build our Markup to input our new stage.

            $element = $this->addInputError_New_Element($option);

        } 
        elseif($option['FormField'] = 'status') {

            // Build our Markup for selecting our status.
            $element = $this->addSelectError_New_Element($option);

        }

        return $element;

    }

    function makeEntireForm() { // next stage is to forget hard coding instead pass in array of elments you want made and cycle through array. 

            /*
            * Create Input field -> Stage
            */
            $entireForm = '';
            $option = array(
                'FormField'     => 'stage',
                'error'         => FALSE,
                'value'         => FALSE,
                'placeholder'   => 'Stage (ie; Scheduled Inspection)',
                'name'          => 'stage',
                'id'            => FALSE,
                'type'          => 'text',
                'label'         => 'Stage',
                'maxchar'       => 50,
                'required'      => TRUE
            );  
            // Build Element
            $entireForm .= $this->addElementToForm($option);

            /*
            * Create Input field -> Status
            */
            $arrayvalues = array('Test','Test2');
            $option = array(
                    'FormField' => 'status',
                    'error'     => FALSE,
                    'label'     => 'Status',
                    'class'     => FALSE,
                    'targetid'  => FALSE,
                    'name'      => 'status',
                    'array'     => $arrayvalues,
                    'value'     => FALSE,
                    'required'  => TRUE
                );
            // Build Element
            $entireForm .= $this->addElementToForm($option);

        return $entireForm;

    }

    function viewLeadStagesMarkup($title,$action,$return) {

        $Form = $this->makeEntireForm();

        $HTML____ = NULL;

        $HTML____ .= '<form class="form-horizontal" action="'. $action .'" method="post">' .
                     '<div class="panel panel-info">' .
                     '<div class="panel-heading">' .
                     '<h3 class="panel-title">'. $title .'</h3>' .
                     '</div>' .
                     '<div class="panel-body">' .
                     '<p>WARNING: Page under maintenance. Please do not use. Hit cancel and go back.</p>' . 
                     '<div class="row">' .
                     '<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">' .
                     $Form .
                     '</div>' .
                     '</div>' .
                     '</div>' .
                     '<div class="panel-footer">' .
                     '<a href="'.$return.'" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="#"></i>Cancel</a> ' .
                     '<div class="pull-right">' .
                     '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Create</button>' .
                     '</div>' .
                     '</div>' .
                     '</div>' .
                     '</form>';

        return $HTML____;
    }

}
```

I have double checked my array values and everything looks spot on? Can someone maybe get a second set of eyes on it and see what they think?

Let me know if you need explanation or need to see any functions that are not listed.

errors are populating from code section

```
// Input Field -> Stage
function addInputError_New_Element($option) {
    var_dump($option);
    $element = $this->FormFields->InputError_NEW(
        $Error = $option['error'],
        $Value = $option['value'],
        $PlaceHolder = $option['placeholder'],
        $InputName = $option['name'],
        $InputID = $option['id'],
        $InputType = $option['type'],
        $InputLabel = $option['label'],
        $MaxChar = $option['maxchar'],
        $required = $option['required']
    );
    return $element;
}
```

result from `var_dump($option);`

```
array(10) { ["FormField"]=> string(5) "stage" ["error"]=> bool(false) ["value"]=> bool(false) ["placeholder"]=> string(31) "Stage (ie; Scheduled Inspection" ["name"]=> string(5) "stage" ["id"]=> bool(false) ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["label"]=> string(5) "Stage" ["maxchar"]=> int(50) ["required"]=> bool(true) } array(9) { ["FormField"]=> string(5) "stage" ["error"]=> bool(false) ["label"]=> string(6) "Status" ["class"]=> bool(false) ["targetid"]=> bool(false) ["name"]=> string(6) "status" ["array"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Test" [1]=> string(5) "Test2" } ["value"]=> bool(false) ["required"]=> bool(true) }
```

FormFields Class Functions i am using.

```
function InputError_NEW($Error, $Value, $PlaceHolder, $InputName, $InputID, $InputType, $InputLabel, $MaxChar,$required) {
        $output = '<div class="control-group">';
        if (!empty($Error)) {
                $output .='<label class="control-label" for="inputError">
                    <i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times-circle-o">
                        <b>'.$Error.'</b>
                    </i>
                </label>';  
        }
        $output .='<label class="control-label">' . $InputLabel . '</label>' .
                '<div class="controls">' .
                '<input class="form-control"';
                    if (!empty($InputID)) {
                        $output .= ' id="' . $InputID . '"';
                    }
                    if (!empty($InputName)) {
                        $output .= ' name="' . $InputName . '"';
                    }
                    if (!empty($InputType)) {
                        $output .= ' type="' . $InputType . '"';
                    }
                    if (!empty($PlaceHolder)) {
                        $output .= ' placeholder="' . $PlaceHolder . '"';
                    }
                    if (!empty($Value)) {
                        $output .= ' value="' . $Value . '"';
                    }
                    if (!empty($MaxChar)) {
                        $output .=' maxlength="'. $MaxChar . '"';
                    }
                    if ($required) {
                        $output .= ' required';
                    }
                    $output .= '>' .
                '</div>' .
                '</div>';
        return $output;   // you will have to echo ($output); in the HTML file
    }

    function SelectError_NEW($Error, $InputLabel, $Class, $DataTargetDIVID, $SelectName, $SelectArray, $Value) {
        $output = '<div class="control-group">';
        if (!empty($Error)) {
                $output .='<label class="control-label" for="inputError">
                    <i style="color:red" class="fa fa-times-circle-o">
                        <b>'.$Error.'</b>
                    </i>
                </label>';  
        }
        $output .='<label class="control-label">' . $InputLabel . '</label>' .
                '<div class="controls">' .
                '<select class="form-control ' . $Class . '" data-target="' . $DataTargetDIVID .'" name="' . $SelectName .'"';
                if ($required) {
                $output .= ' required'; 
                }
                $output .='>
                    <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
                    '.makeOptions($SelectArray, $Value).'
                </select>' .
                '</div>' .
                '</div>';
        return $output;   // you will have to echo ($output); in the HTML file
    }
```

Comment: see if your are getting those values or not `var_dump($option)`

Comment: Changed it to what you put and nothing changed. same errors @Fred-ii-

Comment: the syntax is `__construct()`. you should update your question then

Comment: I realized that after I said it.. I changed it and now getting `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function FormFields()`

Comment: which is coming from the construct

Comment: It is a class that I am trying to create in the `__construct()`

Comment: if class then put `new` keyword and import that class to this class file, may be require/include

Comment: not following @webDev

Comment: If I `include(FormFields.php')` in the class it gives me ` PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class FormFields in` -> referencing to FormFields Class `class FormFields {..` @webDev

Comment: no no see `$FormFields = new FormFields();`, but in your constructor there is `$this->FormFields`, this means you should have a global variable as $FormFields

Comment: this means already included. now you need to delare your global variable into your class as $FormFields above your constructor and then use everywhere as $this->FormFields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140204/discussion-between-kray-and-webdev).

Comment: Still have the same original issue @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Method below was intended to do a quick validation of the input field to create. This posed an issue, and ultimately deprecated this method.

```
function addElementToForm($option) {
        if($option['FormField'] = 'stage') {

            // Build our Markup to input our new stage.
            $element = $this->addInputError_New_Element($option);

        } 
        if($option['FormField'] = 'status') {
            // Build our Markup for selecting our status.
            $element = $this->addSelectNoBlank_New_Element($option);

        }

        return $element;

    }
```

When I was creating the `makeEntireForm()` method I was creating a

```
$entireForm .= $this->addElementToForm($stage_option);
```

which I changed to the following.

```
$entireForm .= $this->addInputError_New_Element($stage_option);
```

by removing this "middle man method" I was able to accomplish my end results.

Answer (score 2):

I meant this (sorry if you did not understand the comments)

```
class LeadStage {
    private $my_object;
    function __construct() {
        $this->my_object = new FormFields(); 
    }

    // Input Field -> Stage
    function addInputError_New_Element($option) {
        //$FormFields = new FormFields();
        $element = $this->my_object->InputError_NEW(
    //...............
    //.................
```

Similarly everywhere do same. To point a variable use `$this` keyword you should have that variable in your class.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class FormFields in /class/FormFields.php on line 18 (which is `class FormFields { ...`)

Comment: see uodated code, and if not solved then post your `FormFields` class code. post `class FormFields { ...}`

Comment: go to the chat i sent the block @webDev

Comment: you are declaring your class twice, remove if you are requiring or including the class `FormFields { ...}`

Comment: I am no longer getting that error. I am back to the orignal error. Unidenfied Index.

Comment: now again you have to make sure that all the data available in your $option array, error msg saying that not index then please check your option array , check its orginal root index, then each level of index. Put manual values instead of $option['placeholder'] etc ... which will run your class i think.

Comment: my array is coming out great when I do a var_dump. @webDev